error with simulator iPhone 15 when I run the app
I have a flutter app and I updated it till last version and I received this error when I tried to run it , any idea?
It's compiling and in the moment it should run this is what I get? it's something I should change in Xcode?

Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file
(/Users/lilianasanda/animo/ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage[arm64][2](GMLImage.o))
built for 'iOS'


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/yr2kFw60.png

